# How to Convert int[] to int[,] - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix

I have an int array in one dimension:

```
var intArray=new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

and I want to convert it to two dimensions, such as:

```
var intArray2D=new[,] { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
```

How do I achieve this with C#?

Comment: What for `{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12}`? `{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}` or `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}`

Comment: Will you always have an even length? Will the Tuple always be a pair? Check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple to see if this helps you define your question better.

Comment: For a single column array to a dual column array one presumes, as it states in his/her question.

Comment: I mean `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` to `{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}` The int[] is x,y coordinate. The first element of the array is the x coord; the second element is the y coord; and so on. I want it to be in an understandable form to assign it to Point[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to split an integer array into an array of two integers each:

```
int[] list = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[][] newlist = new int[list.Length / 2][];
for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < list.Length; i += 2, n++)
{
    newlist[n] = new[] { list[i], list[i + 1] };
}
```

To assign it to `Points` in particular you could try:

```
List<Point> plist = new List<Point>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i += 2)
{
    plist.Add(new Point(list[i], list[i + 1]));
}
```

Comment: Using an array of arrays ([][]), when the 2nd dimension is constant, is inefficient in comparison to one continuous matrix ([,]).

Comment: You are using an array of references to arrays instead of a big array. Write your own test for this or open a book.

Comment: I'm a performance freak too, but I doubt that there will be any tangible performance difference. Will confirm this and get back to you :)

Comment: I'm marking this as answer because of the List<Point> solution. I asked for int[,] to make my question more direct, and use the same technique with Point[]. The List<Point> just makes things easier. Thanks.

Comment: Just finished my tests. Contrary to your beliefs or for some other reason, your suggestion was slower. The first code completed in an average of 6.5 milliseconds on first run, while the version with `int[,]` completed in average of 8 milliseconds. I can post my code somewhere for you to see and the pics, but I'd like you to test it yourself and confirm this. Thanks. ps: Tested using Performance Wizard on VS2010 (.Net Framework 4).

Comment: You need to treat this with long 1st dimension and a lot of iterations. Also compare with block copy.

Comment: We could continue this on chat when you have the time. As I said, I don't think there will be any tangible performance. Of course the result could be different with very large arrays, but that is definitely not applicable in this case as I've demonstrated above.

Comment: Also, make sure you are increasing the least significant index in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

with a loop perhaps:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldArr.Length; i=i+2)
{
    newArr[i/2, 0] = oldArr[i];
    newArr[i/2, 1] = oldArr[i + 1];
}
```

Untested, but should get you pointed in the right direction...

Comment: Only the first items in the array ([0,1]) are assigned values, every other array have the value of 0s.

Answer (score 2):

If the one dimensional array contains the primitive data in [row major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), and the total capacity of the 2 dimensional array equals the length of the one dimensional array, you can use this.

```
int[] source = new int[6];
int[,] target = new int[3, 2];
Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, target, 0, source.Length * sizeof(int));
```

Note that unlike `Array.Copy` and other array/list methods, `Buffer.BlockCopy` operates on a number of *bytes* of data, even if each element of the array is larger than 1 byte. It also only operates on arrays of primitive data types.

Additional references:

- Multi-dimensional arrays are stored in row-major order ([ECMA-335 Partition I, §8.9.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm))
- [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx)

Edit: Here is a complete unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SOTest16203210()
{
    int[] source = new int[6] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int[,] destination = new int[3, 2];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, destination, 0, source.Length * sizeof(int));
    Assert.AreEqual(destination[0, 0], 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(destination[0, 1], 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(destination[1, 0], 3);
    Assert.AreEqual(destination[1, 1], 4);
    Assert.AreEqual(destination[2, 0], 5);
    Assert.AreEqual(destination[2, 1], 6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use this code. in here you can send any length you like. you can "deivde" the arry[] to arry[,] for any lenth.2 or 3 or what ever you like! as long as size % a.length ==0 !!!!

code

```
        static int[,] convert(int[] a, int size)
    {
        int[,] value = new int[a.Length / size, size];
        int counter = 0;
        //
        for (int b = 0; b < value.GetLength(0); b++)
            for (int c = 0; c < value.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                 value[b, c] = a[counter];
                  counter++;
           }
        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the product of the dimensions are the same, the fastest way would probably be to pin the matrix using a fixed statement, then to use the Marshalling class to copy the continuous block from the array to an IntPtr created from the void* you got from the fixed.

You would have to wrap this in an unsafe statement and enable unsafe in the assembly's build config.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
int [] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int [,] b = new int[a.Length/2,2];

for(int i = 0;i<a.Length;i++)
{
    b[i/2,i%2] = a[i];
}
```

Note that i/2 is an integer division, hence both 4/2 and 5/2 will give 2 which is a correct index in 2Darray for the tuple 5 and 6 from the original array. The second index is determined using reminder when divided by 2, it will give 0 if the index is even number and 1 if the index of the item from the original array is odd number.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted this from vb to c#

```
int Size = OldArray.Length;
int[,] NewPoints = null;

if (Size % 2 != 0) {
  //Error - Array has odd number of elements!
} else {
  for (i = 0; i <= Size - 1; i += 2) {
    Array.Resize(ref AllPoints, (i / 2) + 1, 2);
    NewPoints[i / 2, 0] = OldArray(i);
    NewPoints[i / 2, 1] = OldArray(i + 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this for any dimension of array:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void TestMethod2D() {
        var intLinear=new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var indexer2D=new ArrayIndexer<int>(3, 2);

        for(var i=intLinear.Length; i-->0; indexer2D[i]=intLinear[i])
            ;

        var int2D=(int[,])indexer2D.ToArray();
    }

    public static void TestMethod4D() {
        var intLinear=new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var indexer4D=new ArrayIndexer<int>(2, 2, 2, 2);

        for(var i=intLinear.Length; i-->0; indexer4D[i]=intLinear[i])
            ;

        var int4D=(int[, , ,])indexer4D.ToArray();
    }
}

public partial class ArrayIndexer<T> {
    public Array ToArray() {
        return m_Array;
    }

    public ArrayIndexer(params int[] lengths) {
        m_Array=Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), lengths);
    }

    public T this[params int[] indices] {
        set {
            m_Array.SetValue(value, indices.Transform(m_Array));
        }

        get {
            return (T)m_Array.GetValue(indices.Transform(m_Array));
        }
    }

    Array m_Array;
}

public static partial class ArrayExtensions {
    public static int[] Transform(
        this int[] indices, Array array, bool isRowMajor=true) {
        if(indices.Length>array.Rank)
            return indices;
        else {
            var list=indices.ToList();

            if(isRowMajor)
                list.Reverse();

            for(int r, q=0, i=0, count=array.Rank; count-->0; ++i) {
                var index=isRowMajor?count-i:i;

                if(indices.Length>i) {
                    q=Math.DivRem(indices[i]+q, array.GetLength(index), out r);
                    list[i]=r;
                }
                else {
                    if(index<0) {
                        list.Add(q);
                        q=0;
                    }
                    else {
                        q=Math.DivRem(q, array.GetLength(index), out r);
                        list.Add(r);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(isRowMajor)
                list.Reverse();

            return list.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

`ArrayExtensions.Transform` is an indices transformer, it performs the linear transformation with the geometry of a given array. `isRowMajor` controls the layout, such as you would regard an `int[,]` in `x, y` or in `y, x` order.

Comment: [280Z28's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203210/how-to-convert-int-to-int-c-sharp/16204897#16204897) seems better if the element type is primitive.